# Auto Increment Reseed when another ID has been changed on Insert Query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I Have a two ID that can can be a primary key

```
SID DEFECT_ID
  1     1
  1     2
  1     3
  1     4
  1     5
```

`DEFECT_ID` is auto increment `SID` is static and can be another value like 1 or 2 or 3

I need to reseed when sid is another value like this

```
SID DEFECT_ID
  1     1
  1     2
  1     3
  1     4
  1     5
  2     1
  2     2
  2     3
  3     1
  3     2
  1     6
  1     7
```

can it be setting in sql server ?

Comment: You need that output as select query's or in vb.net ??

Comment: i need that on insert query

Comment: Insert query, ? how just explain it, show the insert statement and select for the current example also

Comment: sorry insert query in vb.net

Comment: why you want to reseed? Why just not select your own sequence when you are selecting the data? I mean - does it really need to be that physically in the table?

Comment: @TouchyVivace So you want to update the  the same table with that order  ?? your requirement is unclear (_at least for me_)

Comment: @Vivek.S so `DEFECT_ID` is auto increment and SID can be changed to 1 or 2 or 3 with some reason, but it's not make sense if SID has change to 2 and `DEFECT_ID` is not reseed to 1 

yes i need to update the same table

Comment: You can try this -http://hastebin.com/ikiqecolor.sql

Comment: @Vivek.S thanks i just need this !

Comment: u can set identity insert on in the table and insert explicit values

Comment: You should create a trigger that updates `DEFECT_ID` after Insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OVER Clause(T-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to get the order number of each ID in your table

```
SELECT ID
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id ASC
        ) value
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Thank you @Vivek you save my day

Comment: @TouchyVivace Oh , Glad to hear that and all the best

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a way to do what you're asking, but I have a feeling you might be making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Typically you don't try to "re-seed" like that for identity fields. Instead you end up with output like this:

```
SID DEFECT_ID
  1     1
  1     2
  1     3
  1     4
  1     5
  2     6
  2     7
  2     8
  3     9
  3     10
  1     11
  1     12
```

This is how relational databases generally do it and trying to "go against the grain" simply to have the numbers restart for each unique SID is going to be difficult and error-prone.